# No file or directory - when tried to navigate to a page

Tags: wso2-choreo

When I tried to navigate, i found that, no page was available

I tried to deploy react webpage in Choreo (powered by WSO2) using the docker file. The website is working. But I am not able to navigate to the pages. For instance, when I tried to navigate to the page URL/dashboard, the page comes saying "404 not found". When I checked the runtime error, i saw this below message
" failed (2: No such file or directory) "

This was the dockerfile

```
FROM node:16-alpine as builder
RUN npm install -g pnpm

# WORKDIR /
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN if [ -f "./package-lock.json" ]; then npm install; \
    elif [ -f "./yarn.lock" ]; then yarn; \
    elif [ -f "./pnpm-lock.yaml" ]; then pnpm install;fi
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged:stable-alpine-slim

# Update nginx user/group in alpine
ENV ENABLE_PERMISSIONS=TRUE
ENV DEBUG_PERMISSIONS=TRUE
ENV USER_NGINX=10015
ENV GROUP_NGINX=10015

# COPY --from=builder /build /usr/share/nginx/html/
COPY --from=builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html/
# COPY nginx.conf /usr/local/etc/nginx
COPY nginx.conf /usr/share/nginx

USER 10015
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

This was the nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri /index.html;                 
    }
}
```

Can someone help me with this?